# Exception when creating COM-Object

Tags: c#, com, interop, com-interop

I have referenced an Interop-Assembly, which I have created with tlbimp.exe.
Now, when I create a object of a class from this Interop-Assembly like

```
var allplanInstance = new AllplApplicationClass();
```

This is working on my machine and some customer machines. But on some other Customer-Machines, I will get the following Exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): 
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {D8CFBF83-AFC7-11D2-A4F4-0000D1106F9C} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80004005.
```

I have checked if the CLASS-ID {D8CFBF83-AFC7-11D2-A4F4-0000D1106F9C} is registered in the Registry - this is the case on all machines.

What can I do to find the reason of this problem?

Thanks for your hints.

Comment: Possibly the user operating your program does not have access rights to that registry key ? You could "guard" your object construction by asserting your access to that registry key using the RegistryKey class - this will probably isolate any permission or missing key issues, allowing you to diagnose the 80004005 COM error.

Comment: You need support from the author of this component.  He intentionally fails the request to create a new object but used an error code that means nothing.  E_FAIL is just a description of the quality of the error reporting, it is useless to diagnose the reason.

Comment: I usually use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) for troubleshooting errors like this, it's excellent and free. Configure filters to show only failed WinAPI calls, and see what precedes the that error in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common reason this happens is when deploying these types of applications to 64 bit machines.  If the machine is 64 bit you have to build the calling C# application in x86.  In addition to this the COM dll has to be registered using the 32 bit version of regsvr32.exe which is in the Windows/SysWow64/ folder.